# remoteview framelayout background color

Tags: android, colors, android-framelayout, remoteview

```
int mColor = 0xff00ff00;

remoteView.setInt(R.id.framelayout1, "setBackgroundResource", android.R.color.white);
```

how do i set the color using mColor ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should try

```
remoteView.setInt(R.id.framelayout1, "setBackgroundColor", mColor);
```